# Using plphp - how to write padded hex output to a bytea column in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

TRYING TO WRITE A 12-byte string to PostgreSQL

Our code calculates a $number. We't then like to convert it to hex, pad it left with zeros and write it into a PostgreSQL bytea field. Easy, right?

(As an example) Would like it to return: \x000000002257 ('\x' + 12 bytes)
ie, the left-padded HEX representation of the number 8791:

```
$number = 8791;

$hexnumber = str_pad(dechex($number), 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$packed_hex = pack('h*', $hexnumber);

// BOTH of below produce:  000000002257
pg_raise('notice', "hexnumber:         ".$hexnumber);
```

Cannot get *any* of these queries to update the bytea as I'd wish. Help!

```
//$query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = '".$hexnumber."' WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);

// $query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = '000000002257' WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);
// Above produces:  \x303030303030303032323537
// (makes sense; it's quoted as a string)

// $query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = 000000002257 WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);
// Above produces: ERROR:  column "destfile" is of type bytea but expression is of type integer

// $query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = '8791' WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);
// Above produces:  \x38373931  as expected...

/ $query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = 8791 WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);
// Above produces: ERROR:  column "destfile" is of type bytea but expression is of type integer

// $query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = '"."'".$packed_hex."'"."' WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);
// Above produces:  \x only...

$query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = "."'".$packed_hex."'"." WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);
// unterminated quoted string at or near "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've just forgotten the leading `\x` for a bytea literal. If `$packed_hex` contains `000000002257` you could write:

```
$query = ("UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = '\x".$packed_hex."' WHERE pkey = ".$args[0]);
```

You'll need to `SET bytea_output = 'hex'` on PostgreSQL 9.0 and below (IIRC) to get the bytea back out in hex form not the icky old octal escape format. Newer versions default to `hex`.

### SQL Injection

`<soapbox>` Your code shows a bad habit. Use parameterised queries to avoid SQL injection. `packed_hex` might be generated in your app for now, but who knows how this code could get reused later. Always use parameterised queries to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). See [the PHP manual on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).`</soapbox>`

As written, your code is woefully, horribly insecure. Imagine if `$args[0]` contained `NULL);DROP SCHEMA public;--` from a malicious user. You just sent:

```
UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = '\000000002257' WHERE pkey = 0);DROP SCHEMA public;--);
```

to your database, which did an UPDATE that did nothing, followed by a `DROP SCHEMA public;` that most likely destroyed your database, then a comment that ignores the rest. Whoops, splat, there goes your database, [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) strikes again.

This would be better written as:

```
$stm = pg_prepare($connection, "", "UPDATE blobtest SET destfile = $1 WHERE pkey = $2");
$result = pg_execute($connection, "", array($packed_hex, $args[0]));
```